# react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer Encoding Turkısh Chracter Problem

Tags: javascript, react-native, encoding, printing, thermal-printer

I want to send print Turkish parameter from react-native app to bixolon spp-r310 printer.

My Code is :

```
async print(BBcolumn, txtObj, isBold, addEnterCount, barcode) {
         let txt = null;
           let result = ‘’;
           let space = ‘’;
           try {
               txt = txtObj;
           } catch (e) {
               console.log(‘Print Methot error : ’ + e);
           }
           let spaceLen = BBcolumn.Lenght - txt.toString().length;
           for (var a = 0; a < spaceLen; a++) {
               space += ' ';
           }
           if (BBcolumn.TextAlign === ‘right’) {
               result = space + txt;
           } else if (BBcolumn.TextAlign === ‘left’) {
               result = txt + space;
           }
           isBold === true ? BluetoothEscposPrinter.setBlob(1) : BluetoothEscposPrinter.setBlob(0);
           for (var i = 0; i < addEnterCount; i++) {
               result += ‘\r\n’;
           }
           if (barcode === true) {
               await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printerInit();
               await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printerAlign(BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.CENTER);
               await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printBarCode(txtObj.toString(), BluetoothEscposPrinter.BARCODETYPE.CODE128, 3, 70, 0, 2);
               await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printerAlign(BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.LEFT);
               await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText(‘\f’, {});
           } else {
               // console.log(result);
               await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText(result.replace(‘null’, ‘’),
                   {
                       encoding: ‘CP1254’,
                       fonttype: 1,
                   });
           }
       }
```

I tried Encoding 1254 and ıso88959-9 and  encoding 857(There is not Capital İ therefore It doesn't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your solution:

```js
await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printText(result.replace('null', ''),
{
    codepage: 25,
    encoding: 'windows-1254',
    fonttype: 1,
});
```

codepage is very important.

Comment: please give a reference link for other encodings (same problem with Spanish characters)