# Print Pound sign in react native thermal printer ( react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer )

Tags: react-native, thermal-printer

I am using ( react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer ) to print the receipt with pound sign '₤' . but what i get is '?'. if anyone know the answer please let me know. thanks

existing code is :

```
await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printColumn(
        columnWidths,
        [
            BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.LEFT,
            BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.LEFT,
            BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.CENTER,
            BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.RIGHT,
        ],
        ['', '', 'Total: ','₤'+(totalAmount).toFixed(2)],{}
);
```

Comment: Seems like an old unresolved issue. Better look for other packages. https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer/issues/74

Comment: It depends on both the library and the printer, but is the printer code page a code page that supports pound signs? And is the string to be printed also encoded to match the characters on the code page? For example, these articles. [react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer Encoding Turkısh Chracter Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58482140/9014308), [How to print Unicode text to a Thermal printer using React Native](https://manhtai.github.io/posts/print-unicode-to-thermal-printer-using-react-native/)

Comment: @nisanth reddy that's the last option mate.

Comment: @kunif already tested both the example sir.

Comment: You may be able to get some advice from someone else by adding what the source was when you did those tests and what the results were.